# Append height of video on its name

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to append height of videos on their name, like <video_name>[height].
With the following code, I can get the height of each video. However, I'm stuck on how to append it to the name :

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $path
Foreach ($file in $files) {
$height = ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of csv=s=x:p=0 .\$file
}
```

Comment: Can you show your current output, and your desired output?

Comment: video01.avi -> video01[480].avi (for an height of 480)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your foreach command add

```
Rename-Item $file.FullName -newName "$($file.BaseName+$height+$file.Extension)"
```

So whatever the output you have in $height variable can be added to your new file name.

Comment: i've got a strange error message 
<code>Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at '<valid_path_to_item>' does not exist.
At <path_to_the_script>:19 char:5 
+Rename-Item $file.FullName -newName "$($file.BaseName + '[' + $height + ']'+ $file.Extension)"
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
</code>

Comment: ```$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\PS\'
foreach($file in $files){
$height = ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of csv=s=x:p=0 .\$file
Rename-Item $file.FullName -newName "$($file.BaseName+$height+$file.Extension)"

}``` Assuming that you have only video files in the given path I will do this. Also I tried this with some CSV files.

Comment: Try adding switch `-File` to the Get-ChildItem line, so you do not also try to process directories. It would also make a big difference if you can use `-Filter` on a specific file type to not process files that aren't video's

Comment: ok, with some tests, i identified that the problem came from ' [ ' or ' ] ' characters in the names. Do you know if it's possible to fix it ?

Comment: to summarize and end the post : 
problem solved with the post "Powershell Rename-Item issue with special characters"
thanks for all, it's perfectly working :)

Comment: Please select an answer which really suits you and Mark it as an answer by clicking green tick to close the thread.